# Raspberry pi showing notification of low volatge warning

Tags: pi-3b+

I have a 12V power supply and has used LM2575 for converting 12V to 5V for powering the raspberry pi. I check with multimeter the output after designing circuit it is 5.25V.

Comment: the problem is the amount of current that LM2575 is able to supply

Comment: `I check with multimeter the output after designing circuit it is 5.25V` and what is it when you're powering a pi

Comment: @Bravo when I power the raspberry pi , at the input the voltage drop and  it is 4.50V

Comment: I guess you can see the issue now - your power supply is inadequate

Answer (score 3):

A quick google suggests the LM2575 can only provide 1 Amp output. The Pi3B+ specification states 2.5 Amps.

Make sure you have wires of sufficient diameter to provide that current with as few connections as possible.

LM2575:

> Specified 1-A Output Current

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2575.pdf?ts=1639470491002&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Pi3B+:

> 5V/2.5A DC power input

https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/

Comment: You could have wires the thickness of your thumb, if the LM2575 is incapable of supplying the *current* required by the pi, you'll still have issues